How do I display foreignkey as a search option in Django cms Plugin
I want to be able to use the autocomplete_fields interface from Django admin in a Django CMS plugin
I've created a plugin which has a foreignkey field :
class ProductBlock(CMSPlugin):
    text = models.TextField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

When I go to add the plugin to the page the option is shown as a dropdown.
I've created an admin.py as follows:
class ProductBlockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['product']

admin.site.register(ProductBlock, ProductBlockAdmin)

In the admin section the field appears with the search option but this isn't displayed in the editor for the plugin.
I'm using django cms 4.1.3

I guess, the simplest way is to do the following
class ProductBlockPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    autocomplete_fields = ['product']
    ...

Django CMS plugins do not register their own ModelAdmin, since they already are a subclass of ModelAdmin and already have the autocomplete functionality built-in.
No thinking about jQuery versions, or adding a dependency.
